# Download image with changing name daily

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to get a script that downloads the latest picture from NASA's "Astronomy Picture of the Day" Website to use it as a daily changing background.
Whilst the picture with description is always displayed on https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html or with an iterative number in the archive, the images are named incosistently.
E.g. today's image is located in `<img src="image/1611/nhq201611140001_900x1238.jpg"...>` whereas yesterday's picture is found in `<img src="image/1611/HeartSoul_Lindemann_960.jpg">`

I already found help on how to set the image as a background automatically, I don't know how to proceed with the download.

Comment: This is a place where programmers ask about programming questions. Not where you come to get programmers to write programs for you for free.

Comment: The unfortunate Truth still being that: ***There are still those who are more than willing to FREELY do that*** -  **IRONIC**,  huh? Perhaps they think: ***...by the way, the AIR we all breath never ever asked for nothing in return ... and anyone can breath as much as they like - because the REAL& VITAL things in Life are FREE:     :-(*** .....  Who can stand 7 Full Hours without Air??? Yet it would only take less than 7 Minutes to do this - *for the One whose heart is geared towards being Human.....*

Answer (score 0):

> With `file_get_contents()`, and a mix of `preg_match()` You can get the image you want.

```
<?php

    $data               = file_get_contents("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html");
    $images             = preg_match("#(<img src=\")(.*?)(\".+>)#is", $data, $matches);
    $imageOfTheDay      = null;
    if(sizeof($matches) > 2){
        $imageOfTheDay  = "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/" . $matches[2];
    }
    echo $imageOfTheDay;
```